# Prolog-return all triples of elements in the ring Zm which satisfy the property x + y = z- Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, swish

I am trying to Implement plus(X,Y,Z) , which should return all triples of elements in the ring Z_m that satisfy the property X + Y = Z, etc.

Here is my codes:

```
plus(X,Y,Z):-read(M),A is mod(X,M),B is mod(Y,M),Sum is A+B,Z is Sum mod M.
times(X,Y,Z):-read(M),A is mod(X,M),B is mod(Y,M),Product is A*B,Z is Product mod M.
```

But it is said:

```
Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
In:
   [2] _1430 is _1436 mod 5
   [1] plus(_1490,_1492,_1494) at  line 10
```

I am new to Prolog and I feel so clueless...

Comment: Why are you using `read`? `plus/3` is already available: https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=plus/3

Comment: Can you put your complete program here, especially including the call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've only shown a tiny portion of the program.

The usual choices are:

- Instantiate the variables (obvious)
- Use [freeze](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=freeze/2) or [when](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=when/2) to delay usage
- Use e.g. [clpfd](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=clpfd) or [clpBNR](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/list?p=clpBNR), which can handle arithmetic on vars

Comment: sry i am not sure i understand...the first option is the easiest way, right?

Comment: to be honest I thought that's all I need to write down:(